# SQL: Trying and failing to sort data to display certain months

Tags: mysql, sql, between, dedupeplugin

I'm working on a homework assignment, and all has been well until I got to this point. My professor wants me to pull only dates in MARCH, APRIL, and MAY, without using the BETWEEN operator.

NOTE: I'm not getting any errors. I am using EDUPE, which runs MySQL, but has small variances where some things simply won't work.

Question was, is there a way to make the code I have function properly? Or am I going in the wrong direction?

```
/*Exercise Six*/
SELECT order_id as "Order ID", DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M-%d-%Y') as "Order Date"
FROM orders
WHERE order_date IN ('March%', 'April%', 'May%')
ORDER BY order_date ASC;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: You're asking about MySQL workbench, right? I'm actually running it in an online course provided compiler. Very interesting stuff, but I do have MySQL workbench if there's something you think I do better in there.

Comment: I mean RDBMS, because date functions can differ for each of them.

Comment: Yeah, okay, I see what you mean...at least I think I see what you mean. I do need the day to be there though...but you're right, I need to find a way to pick only one year.

Comment: It has been figured out. I'll just add on to Potashin's solution below: WHERE DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M') IN ('March', 'April', 'May') AND DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y') IN ('2014')

Comment: Tag dbms used. You've got product specific SQL there...

Comment: The between operator is equivalent to using two `<=` and `>=` conditions.

Comment: jarlh Should I suppose that product specific SQL is a bad thing? It's kind of hard to explain, but the compiler I'm using is an online thing that is used in my school but it runs MySQL. Not even sure how...well, common it is. It's EDUPE  ... wvdz would those conditions work with dates? Perhaps if I did it in numerical months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `date_format` again:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M') IN ('March', 'April', 'May')
```

Or just [`monthname()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname):

```
WHERE MONTHNAME(order_date) IN ('March', 'April', 'May')
```

Comment: You have taughten me valuable content. Thank you!   WHERE DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M') IN ('March', 'April', 'May') AND DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y') IN ('2014')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, but you can do this with "union":

```
select order_ID, order_date from orders
where order_date Like '%Mar%'
union
select order_ID, order_date from orders
where order_date Like '%Apr%'
union
select order_ID, order_date from orders
where order_date Like '%May%'
```

EDIT: I prefer Otashin's answer.

Comment: Well it's still nice to know I have options. :) I've never used Union, so that will be fun to play with.